# TWS API (Interactive Brokers) - how to catch event and place order

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers, tws

There was such a problem:
I study TWS API (Interactive Brokers), I understand the methods, classes, etc.
I registered the logic control unit for placing orders and at this stage I can’t understand - how to place orders in the terminal under different conditions of the price received from the terminal? Probably this problem is solved by multithreading, but alas, I can not fully understand how to implement this. I beg you to help. Below is the code that takes data from the terminal, in the main () block - the code for placing an order. I can’t understand how to attach to placing an order - triggering conditions.
Thanks in advance for any help and information.

```
    from ibapi.client import EClient
    from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
    from ibapi.contract import Contract
    from ibapi.order import *

class TestApp(EWrapper,EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)
    def error(self,reqId,errorCode,errorString):
        print("Error:  ",reqId,"  ",errorCode,"  ",errorString)
    def updateMktDepth(self, reqId, position: int, operation: int,side: int, price: float, size: int):
        print(price)
def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)
    es = Contract()
    es.localSymbol = "ESZ9"
    es.symbol = "ES"
    es.secType = "FUT"
    es.exchange = "GLOBEX"
    es.currency = "USD"
    app.reqMarketDataType(4)
    app.reqMktDepth(1, es, 2, False, [])
    app.reqPositions()
    app.reqAllOpenOrders()
# QUESTION -  how  to place order, using any conditions with price? (for example: if price > 3000)
    order = Order()
    order.account = "DU1656058"
    order.action = "SELL"
    order.totalQuantity = 1
    order.orderType = "LMT"
    order.lmtPrice = 3055
    app.placeOrder(11000, es, order)
    app.run()
    app.disconnect()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The TWS API makes it possible to set order submission criteria such as price conditions and volume conditions. The official documentation is [here](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_conditions.html). For example, if an `Order` has a `TimeCondition`, it will only be submitted before or after a specific time.

The book [Algorithmic Trading with Interactive Brokers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0997303735) provides code that demonstrates how order conditions can be set.

Comment: I`ve watch fast  official documentation,  and have now another question - if i want to create my own condition for open order - for example - when SP500 futures makes 1% up - i open long in AAPL stock. Or signal can be not only contract price, but combination:  SP500 / Dow mini futures  and some comparison of this - will be my set up for order openings. Will  i be able to solve this by using official "Conditions methods" ?   Thank you one more time !!!

Comment: I don't think you can do that with order conditions, but you can write code that monitors SPX and automatically submits an order for AAPL (placeOrder) when SPX rises 1%.

Comment: may be you know how construct any own conditions ?  i think there is one simple principle to make it.    I  can get all data from TWS, convert it, make any calculations, write in a data base and so one, but can`t be flexible in condition building for order exec ))  May be i am stupid, or TWS api little bit strange ?! ))  hope first ))